# HandoutMasterPart default constructor always throws error

Tags: java, docx4j

Docx4j version 8.1.2

HandoutMasterPart default constructor does not include a leading / in the default part name. This causes an InvalidFormatException automatically.

Other parts do include the leading /.

```
HandoutMasterPart handoutMasterPart = new HandoutMasterPart();

> org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: A part
> name shall start with a forward slash ('/') character [M1.4]:
> ppt/handoutMasters/handoutMaster1.xml     at
> org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName.throwExceptionIfPartNameNotStartsWithForwardSlashChar(PartName.java:453)
>   at
> org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName.throwExceptionIfInvalidPartUri(PartName.java:221)
>   at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName.<init>(PartName.java:161)
>   at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName.<init>(PartName.java:133)
>   at
> org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PresentationML.HandoutMasterPart.<init>(HandoutMasterPart.java:38)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this; will fix in a new release this week.

In the meantime, you could use:

```
HandoutMasterPart handoutMasterPart = new HandoutMasterPart(new PartName("/ppt/handoutMasters/handoutMaster1.xml"));
```

Comment: See now https://www.docx4java.org/forums/announces/docx4j-8-1-3-and-11-1-3-released-t2837.html